# How to enable children of the laravel User class to use the default authentication middleware

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am working on a school management system where almost every human entity is a User this makes it complex to add all the fields to the User class. 
For example a Student is a User, a Teacher is User and a Parent is Also a User.
All of these entities have access to the system and have different properties. I thought extending the User class for all of these entities will enable them use the **default authentication middleware** since all of them need an email and a password to login.

Here is my user class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use EntrustUserTrait;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And here is how I extend it.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends User
{
    //
}
```

However after trying this and creating a student, I tried authentication and it failed. Need some help please.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "I tried authentification and it failed"? Do you have separate database tables and separate authentication controllers for each child class? Or do you somehow share them? If yes, then how? My suggestion is to implement your desired logic using polymorphic relationship. You could still use User as the base class and append to it the Student or Teacher classes. See this example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations and exchange Comments for Users, Posts for Teachers, Videos for Students.

Comment: Ok thanks, they share separate database tables the student table(migration) has all the columns of user but has additional columns. I did not create any other authentication controller because I expected the default one to work since I extended user.

Comment: The authentication controller has no way of knowing if the provided email+password should be looked for in the Teachers table or Students table. Therefore it won't work the way you originally presumed. You'd have to write your own controllers(s) and you don't want to do that. I suggest looking into the polymorphic relations. They're really useful once you get the hang of them.